# how to put the text below the images without {css}

Tags: html, css

Whenever I'm trying to change `.tea` to `display: block;` all the images change their position from being horizontal, to being vertical

How to position it the correct way so the images keep being horizontally aligned and the text will be underneath

```css
.tea {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 225px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tea h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.tea2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 385px;
}

.tea img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.tea2 img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tea">
  <img class="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <h4>Myrtle Ave</h4>
  <img class="2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <h4>Spiced rum</h4>
  <img class="3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <h4>Berry Blitz</h4>
</div>
<div class="tea2">
  <img class="1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <img class="2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
```

Comment: Share your markup please.

Comment: "*all the images goes vertical line*", please add a [Minimal, **Reproducible** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What you mean without CSS ?

Comment: ok now i guess it can be more understandable :)

Comment: Do you mind adding a wire frame image of what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Use a div to contain each image and its title or text... and the container of all divs should be a flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it like this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#gallery .image-container {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000, -1px -1px 2px #000;
}
#gallery img {
  width: 100%;
}
#gallery .title {
  font: bold 24px monospace;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/800px/svg_to_png/321159/hotwork-sign-arvin61r58.png">
    <p class="title">Image 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you HTML to support what you want. Use a container wrapper around the image and image text.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqupmf5s/

```
<div class="tea">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="1" src="32131">
    <h4>Myrtle Ave</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="2" src="3213">
    <h4>Spiced rum</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img class="3" src="3213">
    <h4>Berry Blitz</h4>
  </div>
</div>

.tea {
    display: inline-flex;
    /* margin-left: 225px; */
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center; }

.tea h4{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; }

.tea2 {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-left: 385px; }

.tea img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    /* padding: 25px; */
    border-radius: 15px; } 

.tea2 img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 30px; }
```